# My Class Based Views are not adding slug as well as tags in the form-valid(self,form) of the Class in Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

```
            # Post Model for addding the Post object to the DataBase
            class Post(models.Model):
                STATUS_CHOICE = [
                    ('draft', "Draft"),
                    ('published', "Published")
                ]
                title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
                slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date="publish", null=True, blank=True)
                author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="blog_posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                body = RichTextField()
                publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
                created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
                updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
                status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default="draft")
                image_upload = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="post_pics")
                # For Tagging Features
                tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

                class Meta:
                    ordering = ('-publish',)

                def __str__(self):
                    return self.title

                def get_absolute_url(self):
                    return reverse('post_detail',
                                   args=[self.publish.strftime('%Y'),
                                         self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                         self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                                         self.slug])


        # url for adding the creating and saving the post object to the Database
        url(r'^create_post/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name="create_post")


    # Class-Based View for adding the Post
    class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'status', 'tags', 'image_upload']

        def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
            return self.object.get_absolute_url()

        def form_valid(self, form):
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.author = self.request.user
            obj.slug = slugify(obj.title)
            obj = form.save()
            obj.tags.add(slugify(obj.title))
            obj.save()
            return super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)


# form for adding the fields to the Post Model
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Posts</title>
</head>
<body class="container" style="text-align:center;border:1px solid red;padding:10px;">
{% include './post/navbar.html' %}
<div class="alert alert-info" style="text-align:center;display:inline-block">
    Create Post
</div>
<div>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:80%;margin:0px auto">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.media}}
        {{form|crispy}}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}">
        <input type="submit" name="Register" class="btn btn-success" value="POST">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the slug added is not saving to the database instead the actual title which user enters in the form is getting saved in the database . Also, I am adding the tags if user fails to enter the tags. In that case, I am entering the tags on the basis of the title by slugification of the title, but the tags are getting added into the Taggit Model but not getting entered in the tags field of the Post Model.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your Post class.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    form post - auto save slug
    """
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: But what to do for tags?

Comment: Its not addimg to the Post Model Object instead it is added to the Taggit Model but not into the Post Model Object.  Why is it so?